# Node.js code ordering -- is it possible that data is emitted before the listener is in place

Tags: javascript, node.js

This code from Professional Node.js Building Javascript-based Scalable software:

```
var spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// Spawn the child with a node process executing the plus_one app
var child = spawn('node', ['06_plus_one.js']);

// Call this function every 1 second (1000 milliseconds):
setInterval(function() {

  // Create a random number smaller than 10.000
  var number = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10000);

  // Send that number to the child process:
  child.stdin.write(number + "\n");

  // Get the response from the child process and print it:
  child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('child replied to ' + number + ' with: ' + data);
  }); 
}, 1000);

child.stderr.on('data', function(data) {
  process.stdout.write(data);
});
```

The child process simply increment the number passed from the parent. Is it possible that `child.stdin.write()` goes to child process and before parent register its `data` listener that the child already emit the `data` event?

Also a second question. The code originally had incorrect child program file name and that throws an error. How do I catch error from spawn?

Comment: Test child script existence by calling `fs.readFile` or `fs.readFileSync` at the start of the parent and look for no errors and non-zero length.  This won't tell you if the child script is valid but will identify missing scripts sooner.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- WARNING, memory leak detected! Don't attach a listener inside a loop (setInterval). Every second you're adding a listener. Put this code outside the setInterval callback:

  ```
  child.stdout.on('data', function(data) {
      console.log('child replied to ' + number + ' with: ' + data);
  });
  ```

---

- **The child process simply increment the number passed from the parent. Is it possible that child.stdin.write() goes to child process and before parent register its data listener that the child already emit the data event?**

  No. Two reasons:

  - Read the previous comment. You MUST attach the listener outside the setInterval(), just like `stderr.on("data")`.
  - The child will send the message in a later tick. In the current loop tick you write the message and in a future tick you get the response from the child. This is the definition of asynchronicity with 1 thread (in the javascript layer).

---

- **Also a second question. The code originally had incorrect child program file name and that throws an error. How do I catch error from spawn?**

  Have you tried try-catching the spawn() function?

Comment: I tried try{} catch(err) {} and it doesn't seem to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

> The child process simply increment the number passed from the parent.
>   Is it possible that child.stdin.write() goes to child process and
>   before parent register its data listener that the child already emit
>   the data event?

since the stream.write operation is trully async, NO.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But then why is that for streamwriter I noticed that if I do `outstream.end()` and then `outstream.write()`, if I don't have code catching errors (`outstream.on('error', function(err){})`) already run, it will throw on not having an error handler, despite being async?